# A function to take three integers and return a list of integers and alphabet-letters

Tags: code-golf, string, sequence, alphabet

### Challenge

We take three positive integers `a`, `b`, and `c` as input. Using these integers, first create a sequence in the range `[0, c]` (inclusive on both ends), in steps of `b`. For example, for `a=4, b=2, c=100`, the sequence would be `[0,2,4,...,96,98,100]`.

For every number in this sequence which is divisible by `a`, replace it with the next letter in the lowercase alphabet, starting with the letter 'a' and  wrapping back around to 'a' after you reach 'z'.

### Example:

Input: `a=4, b=2, c=100`
Output: `a2b6c10d14e18f22g26h30i34j38k42l46m50n54o58p62q66r70s74t78u82v86w90x94y98z`

### Challenge rules:

- You can assume that `a`, `b`, and `c` are positive integers only, where `b ≤ a ≤ c`.
- You can assume `a` is a multiple of `b`.
- You can assume `c` is divisible by `b`.
- The preferred output is a single concatenated string as above, but a list/array is acceptable as well.

### Test cases:

```
Input: a=4, b=2, c=100
Output:
a2b6c10d14e18f22g26h30i34j38k42l46m50n54o58p62q66r70s74t78u82v86w90x94y98z

Input: a=9, b=3, c=174
Output:
a36b1215c2124d3033e3942f4851g5760h6669i7578j8487k9396l102105m111114n120123o129132p138141q147150r156159s165168t174

Input: a=10, b=2, c=50
Output:
a2468b12141618c22242628d32343638e42444648f

Input: a=25, b=1, c=25
Output:
a123456789101112131415161718192021222324b

Input: a=6, b=6, c=48
Output:
abcdefghi

Input: a=6, b=3, c=48
Output: a3b9c15d21e27f33g39h45i

Input: a=2, b=1, c=100
Output: a1b3c5d7e9f11g13h15i17j19k21l23m25n27o29p31q33r35s37t39u41v43w45x47y49z51a53b55c57d59e61f63g65h67i69j71k73l75m77n79o81p83q85r87s89t91u93v95w97x99y
```

**I'd really like to see an answer in PHP**, but this challenge is open to any language. This is [codegolf](/questions/tagged/codegolf), so the answer should be as short as possible. [Standard rules apply for functions/programs](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) and [default loopholes are forbidden](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default).

Comment: Also consider using [The Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to get advice and feedback on questions before posting it to main.

Comment: Hi welcome to PPCG! Although I like the challenge itself, the description is lacking a lot of things. As mentioned by @JoKing A [primary winning tag](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/908/52210) is mandatory, where `[codegolf]` is the most common one I would recommend. Also mentioned by JoKing, making it language specific is not recommended. It's best to open it to all languages instead. As for the challenge itself, please specify a bit more and add a few more test cases. Based on the example I can see the range is `[0,c]`, but this should be clear without looking at the example.

Comment: I think all you need to do is change the title to something more descriptive and this is good to go

Comment: Is it necessary to output a string where all the numbers/letters are concatenated or can we also return a list?

Comment: I prefer concatenation of numbers and letters but a list is also ok

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing your challenge so it can be re-opened. Next time please use the Sandbox as advised to perfect a challenge before posting it in the main. Please take a look at what I've edited so you know this for future challenges. If anything is incorrect or I misinterpret something, feel free to edit it again.

Comment: Wow thank you @KevinCruijssen , this is really it. Thank you very much and next time I will use the sandbox as advised

Comment: @labmann You're welcome. Now all we have to do is wait for re-open votes (you've already got 3 and need 5), and then the answer (hopefully including a PHP one) will come in. PS: You're lucky I had the time to edit your challenge. ;) And that it's a good challenge to begin with, otherwise I wouldn't have bothered. Enjoy your stay, and I indeed hope to see you use the Sandbox to perfect challenges before posting them here next time.

Comment: It seems none of your test-cases wrap around from `'z'` to `'a'`. Could you please include one that does?

Answer (score 8):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 67 bytes

First of all, thanks for posting such a cool challenge! I really enjoyed solving it :) Now, here's my 67 byte solution:

```php
<?for(;$i<=($p=$argv)[3];$i+=$p[2])echo$i%$p[1]?$i:chr($l++%26+97);
```

To run it:

```php
php -n <filename> {a} {b} {c}
```

Or [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBCoAgEADAz2ygSAczilLpIeIhpFIIXSx6flvHGYxIZJa9VKYhGcsALaz1eLhT/h9hAV3n@RZigdT8kH6BNIdYGZxCNN0gppFrIppIkRz7t@CdSr6ozR8)

---

Here's the same solution ungolfed and with explanation comments:

```php
$a      = $argv[1];
$b      = $argv[2];
$c      = $argv[3];
$letter = 'a';
for ($i = 0; $i <= $c; $i += $b) {
    if ($i % $a) { // If $i is divisible by $a, the modulo (%) operator will return a remainder of 0, which PHP sees as a falsey value.
        echo $i;
    } else {
        $letter++;
        $letter %= 26; // Wrap $letter around to `a` after it gets to `z`.
        echo chr($letter + 97); // Use PHP's chr function to get the character. 97 is the index of `a`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php
    }
}
```

---

I did a 60 byte solution, but it doesn't wrap around :(

```php
<?for($l=a;$i<=($p=$argv)[3];$i+=$p[2])echo$i%$p[1]?$i:$l++;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchJCoAwDADAz0SoFKEuJ2voQ6QHEZdAaYKKzzf2OCOnqE5h58tAwsUDTWhAEJbreOu5j2UsgsxdrLf1ZKCqoI0BaIRkrVfVQTttnftYHuJ8a5N/)

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 15 bytes

```
;0ôWV £CgX/U ªX
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=OzD0V1Ygo0NnWC9VIKpY&input=NAoyCjEwMA==)

#### Explanation

```
;0ôWV £CgX/U ªX    Implicit: U, V, W = inputs
;                  Reset C to the lowercase alphabet (among other variable resets).
 0ôWV              Create the inclusive range [0...W], using a step of V.
      £            Map each item X by this function:
       CgX/U         Get the character at index (X / U) in the lowercase alphabet. If X is
                     not divisible by U, this is a non-integer and the result is undefined.
             ªX      In this case (literally, if falsy), replace it with X.
                   Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Comment: [14 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=O/VUVyCjQ2dYL1Ygqlg=&input=MTAwCjQKMgotUA==) taking input in the order `c,a,b`.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>65</s> 63 bytes

```r
function(a,b,c,z=seq(0,c,b)){z[x]=rep(letters,sum(x<-!z%%a));z}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNRJ0knWafKtji1UMMAyErS1Kyuiq6ItS1KLdDISS0pSS0q1ikuzdWosNFVrFJVTdTUtK6q/Z@mYaJjpGNoYKD5HwA)

*2 bytes saved thanks to JayCe!*

Returns a list of strings, as R will coerce numbers to strings. To print, simply replace the trailing `z` with `cat(z,sep="")`.

Comment: It looks like the `l=` is not required. [TIO](https://tio.run/##Pc/NToNAFIbhvVeBJCaQjMmcnzlzJsqVGBdAh/5IWwpUK8Zrr5A2zuqsnu@d/tokr8/X5nyox@3xkJWmMrWZiiGeMjtfVZ7/TG@X96KPXdbGcYz9YIbzPru8Pj9OT09lnr905TDGbDL1sW3LbohFmua/1yZjgwaszZOiSNISK6nBroAjaIO4RtmQ3RLvSD8YW5a9swfHR6ed4Emk93bwPHo9K36qfAV7CfwddEofmqwsgkmqgkxSF@D5PkFSAYKrEZBXZIkiBcaG1cHaebEbEQlb77zulNV/BArSgkWwbg/L4wOgBaQjYADCDkiB4QTswdkenIALA4gD0XGevZWAXVJwSXH/n2XRpYVBQGtEZBTUFSExCWlkZGZhbW4EuoWAhUB3J@YMduI1gJ3LEGjG5mHwoBBwjp5VQq5ugiyALADrHajqVWzWm216/QM)

Comment: @JayCe ah of course. I put it there to prevent it from having to generate too many values, but it is un-golfy to do that!

Answer (score 5):

## Clojure, <strike>84</strike> <strike>79</strike> 77  bytes

```
#(for[i(range 0(inc %3)%2)](if(=(mod i %1)0)(char(+(mod(/ i %1)26)(int \a)))i))
```

Givin' Lisp a little love

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxNDoIwFAav8iWG8F5c2JYfdeHKYyCLBovWQGlqXXh6LKi7ySQz3TA9XsHM5IN1cXCgUXtQ79BE84xn/TQtSHs/vOcN9VNoLAXtbgaCrOuQFZwpbsn2dKJxusIiY8HU3XWg7WJotzpVcwoiLpqZLfP83zOjyamEghSCkdMRBeS@XFCKpKvVqgoSqlqwRo3y8KXiR6le@zadPw)

(-7 bytes thanks to @NikoNyrh!)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Do you know what needs to be added to call the function and print the result on [Try it online](https://tio.run/##HchBCoAgEAXQqwyE8IcWeYFOUi3GKctIDanzm7R8T698vmWrFT5NQo50QZSbOgSPETGvZEjYMvSQgh7Db4T00CzMbBhF0r6Rbaek7FrW@gE "Clojure – Try It Online")?

Comment: @Laikoni I added a "Try it online" to my post. I also corrected an error in my code, so thanks for reminding me!

Comment: Good job :) you can save 3 bytes if you make the outer function via `#(...)` and use `fn` to express the inner one. While you are at it you can replace `map` with `for` construct and save further 4 bytes.

Comment: @NikoNyrh good observation!

Comment: And `%1` can be replaced by `%` ;)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>17</s> 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
/Ý¹*εD³ÖiA¾è¼}?
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@MagicOctopusUrn*.

Takes the input in the order `bca`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AScA2P8wNWFiMWX//y/DncK5Ks61RMKzw5ZpQcK@w6jCvH0///8zCjQ4CjY) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##JYvBasJAGITv/1MMeNGiuLsmUaEgBSnk3oqlgmySH1zaGrpZxR7yGt567wvoSTwk975STCIMM8zwjfB1JLkaP4evYbhYVsPyd/nwf5q/lUfzVFzLv@KSz6p8VZxn9F5cVVAeO/WE/BvA4wAvG5Oh1i7jBC6F5Ywd3IYRp7utY7vea2t09MmIdPzRIGab8AEC3dQ2NWJ8pZbBBx27PjQSszeZaR8/UEGvUiSFII9GJMceTUmRL@qJJCm/UUDepLbRPWRLqxs).

**Explanation:**

```python
/               # Divide the second (implicit) input `c` by the first (implicit) input `b`
                #  i.e. 2 and 100 → 50
 Ý              # Take the range [0, `divided_c`]
                #  i.e. 50 → [0,1,2,...,48,49,50]
  ¹*            # Multiply it with the first input `b`
                #  [0,1,2,...,48,49,50] → [0,2,4,...,96,98,100]
    εD          # For-each in this list:
      ³Öi       #  If the current number is divisible by the third input `a`:
                #   i.e. 8 and `a=4` → 1 (truthy)
                #   i.e. 10 and `a=4` → 0 (falsey)
         A      #   Push the lowercase alphabet
          ¾     #   Push the counter_variable (which starts at 0 by default)
           è    #   Index the alphabet with this counter_variable (wraps around by default)
         ¼      #   Increase the counter_variable by 1
            }   #  Close the if
             ?  #  Output without new-line
                #  (If the if was not entered, the input is implicitly output as else-case)
```

Comment: This seems to be working, but what language is this please. And can I break it into a php function and how?

Comment: The language is 05AB1E. A link to the github and is in the title of my post. And I'm afraid this language is completely different than PHP.. 05AB1E is designed for codegolfing, whereas PHP is a hypertext pre-processor for web development. I would advice to edit the challenge description and make it available for all languages, but state you prefer a PHP answer. Once it's re-opened I'm sure someone who is skilled with PHP is able to make a code-golf answer for it. If you need any help editing/fixing your challenge let me know.

Comment: `/Ý¹*vyD³ÖiA¾è¼}?` is 16, just duplicates the `y` instead of using `ë`, which `?` will ignore if it pushes an alphabet char. Actually, `/Ý¹*εD³ÖiA¾è¼}?` works for 15 even, because we are over-writing the output array then you can tie the current winner >:).

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Thanks! :) Forgot about the implicit `ë`.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 62 bytes

```javascript
(a,b,c)=>(g=k=>k>c?'':(k%a?k:Buffer([97+x++%26]))+g(k+b))(x=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdHbToNAEAbge5@CG1MI2O4c9tSEmvgaxgtYdoHSlqYe0vryuJpGDZrs5fxf/tnZVm/Vszv1x5e7w9j4KZRTWhV14bJyk7blUG6GjbtfLNbpcFvdD@uH1xD8KX20Oj/n@S2qpyzL23TI6yxLz6XIJjcensedX@7GNg1pwkWCRQJCZFmyWiUV1sqBaIA9mIDYoupI9MRbMgPjjtVeioPkcblcXqx5v5lxtkgocpqvHKkaEKRDQG5IEHmyjIGNhFZqJTqllO21jNxLTM04EF/tEvndjpX5BBkUGIeIjApNQ0hMioxnZGbFJswglLFUhFBeIYgJqbSxIAAiSJGUEdVgwKKIdREJuZ7vp4rPl7C5OrVrfGi7/p85@j1HtXUgGwSPOhC1ZDuWf1L41fLnGFCTk432NgC0QB3IHvQW7ICwQ9qjPKAe0R7j752tvUwf)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 10, <s>93</s> 83 bytes

```
(a,b,c)->{var r="";for(int i=0;i<=c;i+=b)r+=i%a<1?(char)(i/a%26+97):i+"";return r;}
```

Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##pVPfb9MwEH7nrzCRkBLFFN/5Rxy6gpBgEgLEA4/THhzXad2laZe4ZWPq3z6cdh3d4I1L4kui777vzr5bmK15vZhe3a83VeMtsY3pe/LN@JbcvSDRfBtcVxvryPlq9fBvsB@h8@2MVKZLI4QYOiBJdXA2G@@Bu/36QN0HE6LbrvyULKNAeqC4uCSmm/XZCfegVMdnQu5TQytqs9fv7ramI90kScb16iDpJ2zszyZ27PNJlXX5xL8yZ/A@tXPTZal/Y16hyssie@vzGNW5sOla0o1390eZ8aNgpBvSiIJ3gpYUGEVJVbxg9xxUDSCknCKFCOD/gNgBAoxRKASVey6hhxuLE@xj9e5m7Wxw0yEqMVgpC2wKwoGuEWeo5px5LhZcXwlshFpK1kqxknqt8FqprmB9IUKhNxq3Wv0s2U0pbkv9K6GJ4aoCBGkRUEw549zxUmAttISZLBSbK6VKX8hCL7TQxVXJS9UAQ2ByCYOJFpAB8hVgCRzXwDUIuAZRgGQdSAWy7EFJUDrEagdNFEoPqgIUaIuIAhXqKUcuuOLaCRRCKKHrARyphVSFLoFFNQQewyIZFKChxJhIjOcoqgFb2amrZ3O/L6wqLcgpgsOi5nzGy7mQ/hS1uGqW7Wp93fVhs/15c/vLVMnJ7j82Udx1No7ujJhR49pZmI9JnvvTdhwsuD6ksScpMRf@kpJqv9r9ejzA@JH9UdidTkDntya4JyOwZ3zo9MPUPJshepyxI3/29/gZGzamiTVEktEwi5EjxtuTPHydHglG7jqi@/QQlT2v8cdtH9xytNqEUUy4DU2bJmmSmzyhJMmrg7N5kpHJu/h2YMkTkn7/kiWnlRPX9O7/yI8pR/qXkydi5x8@f/308angw1bv7n8D). Thanks to [Scrooble](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73884/scrooble) for golfing 10 bytes.

Ungolfed:

```
(a, b, c) -> { // lambda taking 3 integer arguments and returning a String
    var r = ""; // we build the result String in steps
    for(int i = 0; i <= c; i+=b) // loop over the range [0,c] in steps of b
        r += i % a < 1 ? (char) (i / a % 26 + 97) : "" + i; // if i is a multiple of a, append the next letter to r as a char, else append i
    return r; // return the result
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>60</s>  50 bytes

```perl6
->\a,\b,\c{[~] (0,b...c).map:{$_%a??$_!!('a'..'z')[$++%26]}}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##ZVBNU9swEL37V4iMqZPGGO1qJcukhl650EtvhGFs2UkMiWNih/Ix4a@nUsIQWjwjr@btm/ehplzN1XbdluxRRWbkeYtn9s0si5Kl25PzcRaO83BsXq/fblifh3kURWYQLbLm7NW/Pc4uLvzbo6N@kAVRFLwEg2t/ODxGdbPZbP3vl1dRPT@papay3rge172RE//ZlW1noXlVl@1eyWNscdae2sFYkKUB839k55YyLoYsCIM9nu/w/Atudrh5x/fYr3XXrLszt1jurrvtlduejuxv6AxCN/L9MHa8fZBD1svSPSVP9xyTOlLP23juqX7bCiOvmWc1G@76jLzJcvVe7eSc9ZmfhczP7TH2lE9NabqysNeibA0bMFe5apl7576lWqZvBl@Z3mZ7WbsmLEvJhUGXBDj33ht6GebKAC@AStATxCmqmeCVoDuh7wnnpBaS15KWUjcKH5RaxbyNqYv1WuOjVn8S/pTQc6JfPO/DKnFWYmcV08FKqBwQpEFAKgQXohQJ4YS0hKmMFZ8ppZIqlrG@06Tj@0Qkag4cgcsFuI9qQA4oloAJCGxAaCB4AIpB8hVIBTJpQUlQunPOh0TAP9rLz@VJaZeJQIE2iEioUBcCBQkldElIRIr05JMUSicFTgrlQcrGIqlinQC3SRGEFbVBIAYNCdoSVl0g5Z@UlBNSToj0QSg3RTmZzqr/ieJfIstEnhiQBUKJ8USIqUhmJKu/)

```perl6
{$^a;(0,$^b...$^c).map:{$_%$a??$_!!chr 97+$++%26}}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##bVBdU9swEHz3rxAZ04QmBN3pJEtJDX3lhb70kYGxZSUxJI6JHcrHpH89lRKG0FLNSKfZ29nbvdqt5mq7bhx7VEM7jqLFM/til4Vj6fY1vsnGPT6Ib/LhcBjf2JPhIqtHr/HtcZxdXMS3R0d2tmIm6cf9/jGqzWYbf728Glbz07JiKetcV9dVZxwkv7euaT00LyvX7FUixhaj5swXxrpZ2mXxt@zcU66LPusOuns83@H5J9zucPuG77Ef67Zet6PQWO6@u@5V6J6N/dMPAwah5Ptiffn9Th6wTpbuKXm659g0kDrRJgoL@ukjjKN6nlWsv8szjibL1Vu003PWY3E2YHHur/XXPdXOtq7w38I1lp2wELkosykL@@15sufGfql3y7IahWzBZdn8r/1ZL9psL6uQl2UpBcsY/ALn0dseogxzZYEXQA70BHGKaiZ4KehO6HvCOamF5JWkpdS1wgelVglvEmoTvdb4qNUvw58MPRv9EkXvo0wYJXajEjqMEioHBGkRkArBhXDCEE5IS5jKRPGZUsqUiUz0nSad3Bth1Bw4ApcLCIcqQA4oloAGBNYgNBA8ACUg@QqkAmkaUBKUbsPkgyPg7@nlx/CkdPBEoEBbRCRUqAuBgoQS2hESkSI9@SCFMkhBkEJ5kPK2SKpEG@DeKYLwot4IJKDBoA/h1QVS/kFJBSEVhEgfhHJbuMl0Vv5LFH8TWSZyY0EWCA6TiRBTYWYkyz8)

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with parameters $a,$b,$c

  $^a; # declare param $a, but don't use it
       # (so $a can be used in the inner block)

  (
    0, $^b ... $^c  # the base sequence

  ).map:            # for each of those values
  {
    $_ % $a         # is it not divisible by `$a` ( shorter than `%%` )

    ??  $_          # if it isn't divisible just return it

    !!              # otherwise return the following

        chr         # a character from the following number

          97 +      # 'a'.ord +
          $++       # self incrementing value (starts at 0)
          % 26      # wrap around back to 'a'
  }
}
```

Comment: You're losing a byte by using `->\a,\b,\c`: use just `$^a` etc. And `chr 97+$++%26` is quite a bit shorter than `("a".."z")[$++%26]`. Finally, you can omit the concatenation because the challenge does not require it. That would save 10 bytes in total, [leaving 50](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1olLtE6N7FAoVolXlUl0d5eJV5RMTmjSMHSXFtFW1vVyKxWR8NARyUuSU9PTyUuWbP2vzUXV3FipUKahomOkY6RqYGmXgHQTOv/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>74</strike>  72 bytes

```c
i,l;f(a,b,c){for(i=l=0;i<=c;i+=b)i%a?printf("%d",i):putchar(l++%26+97);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcrRCoMgFIDh@x5DEI54Bmpla072LOZwO1AtWruKnt0Fu2t3Px9/PD1izJmwdwkCdhjFml4zkO@9cnT10ZH0nSAebtNM45KA8TtDEpfps8RnmKGXkhsr20a4LQ@BRhBrkaBCg1op4Yp9fANjeyVosUTdVAfVap/r42tq1Gjqg1q0WJ3/sPzhlr8)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>80</s> 70 bytes

Returns a list, since the OP said that is acceptable.

```
lambda a,b,c:map(lambda x:x if x%a else chr(x/a%26+97),range(0,c+1,b))
```

Very different approach from the [other Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170230/73884).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzLDoIwEEXX@hWzIWnDJLblJSR@ibqYViokUEhlUb@@ArI7Obn3zN@lm5yKFm7wiAON@kVAqNE0I83sEKEJ0FsICUE7fFownWfhQokq07ri6Mm9WybQpBI159FOHtge4dA7uLMcFUohOAKrMUNZ5RtKsepit6pAiarYsMQS8@ufsoP2/7p8NufT7Hu3gF37oBEMjz8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>65</s> 63 bytes

Returns a list, since the OP said that is acceptable.

```python
lambda a,b,c:[[chr(n/a%26+97),n][n%a>0]for n in range(0,c+1,b)]
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##DYxLDoIwFADX9BTdmLTyEtvyUUhwJ1sPgCwKFmmCD1JqlNNjV5PMJLNsfpxR7UP12Cf97p6aauigL5umHx3Dkz6oPC7OHLBt8KCvoh1mR5FapE7jyzABfSyh4@3@He1kqCxJ5N1W1tXAjhaXj2eck8j8erN4ervXN@fCQa/UlOZnQyXR4ix6OtnVs5rvKSiQQpACEpDnlEgRRCaIykCCykgOOaSXgCTgDw)

---

Previous versions used during the creative process (working backwards):

**84 bytes**

Returns a generator expression.

```python
def f(a,b,c,x=0):
    for n in range(0,c+1,b):yield n%a and n or chr(x%26+97);x+=n%a==0
```

**111 bytes**

Uses a generator for the alphabet and returns a list.

```python
def g(x=0):
    while 1:yield chr(x%26+97);x+=1
A=g()
f=lambda a,b,c:[n%a and n or next(A)for n in range(0,c+1,b)]
```

Comment: Ah, right. That wasn't an option when I was using `next`. Nice.

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 23 bytes

```
q~),@/f%{0W):W26%'a+t}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7BOU8dBP0212iBc0yrcyExVPVG7pFb1/39LBWMFQ3MTAA)

```
q~                              a b c
  ),                            a b [0…c]
    @/                          b [[0…a-1] [a…2a-1] ... […c]]
      f%                        [[0 b…a-b] [a a+b…2a-b] ... […c]]

        {0          t}%         Replace each first with:
          W):W26%'a+            ++W % 26 + 'a'
```

Reading input as `b a c` and dropping the `@` would be 22 bytes (not sure if that's valid).

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 79 bytes

*Note: Not too good at PHP*

```php
<?for(@$l=a;$i<=($p=$argv)[3];$i+=$p[2])$o.=$i%$p[1]?$i:substr($l++,-1);echo$o;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBDoIwEAXQy3ySNhVD0ZVlgvcgXQBBaUKYSYse35Hle7KKate/OJsnNhoDUkcGQhjz@2uHWzzHEWRoowVfCak64WOP9CifqRzZYHPuUnsblnllcFDVu7bqm@bHciTei9b7Hw)

---

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 84 bytes

This is just the same above code just in function format (since you wanted a PHP answer maybe this is better for you)

```php
function f($a,$b,$c,$l=a){for(;$i<=$c;$i+=$b)$o.=$i%$a?$i:substr($l++,-1);return$o;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcpdC4IwFIDh6/YrRpxgw5M4P/qa5h8JQkVzENs46VX0280u06sXHl7f@ykvfe9ZS@ToTq13NBj7EJHUUzfaZjDO8k5AhVAjNAjPopLvzpHQYPICmjlBAbUEFxZgdlCVYC6vsX4NJOAZBLhXUlM7jGTB6c/UNr3jbNOJFGNUUSR5yLc3e7NbHv74jAmqY7pkFc17trrjDBXG2ZIPeMD0tNbkX5lmrLxOXw)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 76 bytes

Takes input, `a`,`b`, and `c` from `[A1]`, `[B1]` and `[C1]`, respectively then outputs to the VBE immediate window.

```vb
For i=0To[C1]Step[B1]:j=i Mod[A1]:?IIf(j,i,Chr(97+k)):k=(k-(j=0))Mod 26:Next
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 83 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b,c,s=0,p=0:c>=s and[chr(p%26+97),`s`][s%a>0]+f(a,b,c,s+b,p+(s%a<1))or''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3NCoMwEITvfYq9FBOyhxj/qlRfRASTiCi0MSRe@vRpDMIe5pthduzv3A4jQlj7j/yqRYJEhRp9z9H2vNND70GaZdSbI/YpatY2FGc/T6N/yoFPbCV3gym0jET3nVN6uCwL6@HiO1AIGnYDpEQQCDnnFIG0CEWEprwg5ymqUiKq6EeuLqgR4pWvWxdJdw8A63ZzwrWeBmj4Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## Kotlin, <s>80</s> 79 bytes

-1 thanks to [O.O.Balance](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/79343/o-o-balance)!

```
{a,b,c->var s="";for(x in 0..c step b)s+=if(x%a>0)x else(x/a%26+97).toChar();s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7dasJAEEav61N8CMIurukaE39iE5Be9bpPMAlZuzRuZHeVFPHZ0yV6USsMfMOZw8x8t77Rpj9TA5WBUYYP4wXKe1ZDcswKfHqrzR55fyFRimpWnMnC5ePxVrWWddAGMooqOF8fUXI3zbVi3YQKyTvUjatZ90qTeDndrHjk2/cvsoxv3bVXJ4MDacPI7l2GnbX083a7VnBcRi/H0PrGMMUSgVhgLiXnf/FGYBHwKnnEczno6T87ToMbJukjXgqEStZPdPFM738Mm6/9Lw)

My first time golfing (or doing anything else) in Kotlin! Probably can be improved.

Very similar to [this Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170224/73884), I realized after writing it. Save on the `return` and lose on the ternary for almost the same score.

Comment: It's not much, but -1 byte by omitting the space after the `else`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python3 - <s>111</s>, <s>101</s>, <s>98</s>, 94 bytes

```
q=iter(map(chr,range(97,123)))
[next(q)if x%a==0else x for x in[y*b for y in range((c+b)//b)]]
```

Probably not the shortest, but there's room for improvement

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCsMgEADvecVeCrttoCYplBz2JSEHFdMIrRprQV9vk/YyMHOYUNLq3VAl3xrFfaO5E6JubJOJ@JIB9RrbKN3D4Hhvu34gosZ/Ek/O5IQbgV0gnySzAPN8G8iw@LjTOpjKWf2sHPafWJcQ9UXRVRHNcw3xKPuQ6hc)

Comment: You can remove a few spaces `next(q)if x%a==0else x for x in[y*b`

Comment: @mbomb007 Good call, didn't realize you could do that. Thanks!

Comment: You may like to view [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54/34718)

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](http://www.sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>64</s> 63 bytes (*ouch*)

```
97:Y;riri:Bri\/),[{B*}*]{X\_@\%0={Yc\Y):Y'{i={97:Y;}&}{X\}?}fX;
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=97%3AY%3Briri%3AB%3Bri2%2F1%2B%2C%5B%7BB*%7D*%5D%7BX4%250%3D%7BYc%5CY)%3AY%3B%7D%7BX%5C%7D%3F%7DfX%3B&input=4%202%20100)

**Explanation**

```
97:Y;                                                                 Set a variable "Y" to the ASCII value of 'a' and pop the variable from the stack
     ri                                                               Read one chunk of the input (Space-delimited)
       ri:B                                                           Set a variable "B" to the next input chunk
           ri\/                                                       Divide the next input chunk by the top value in the stack (B)
               1+                                                     Add one to make the values inclusive
                 ,                                                    Turn it into an array
                   {B*}*                                              Multiply all the array values by B
                  [     ]                                             Capture the results in an array
                         {                                   }fX      Massive for loop
                          X\_@\%0=                                    If X modulo (A value) equals zero
                                  {                   }               If condition true
                                   Yc\                                Push the character with an ASCII value of Y
                                      Y):Y                            Increase the value of Y
                                          '{i=                        If Y's value is that same as that of "{" (the character after z in ASCII)
                                              {97:Y;}                 Set Y's value back to ASCII 'a'
                                                     &                If-only flag
                                                       {  }           If condition false (from X\_@\%0=)
                                                        X\            Push X onto the stack
                                                           ?          If-else flag
                                                               ;      Pop A value from the stack
```

---

This could definitely be made better so feel free to join in!

---

#### Changes

[Helen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58707/helen) cut off a byte!

Old: `97:Y;riri:Bri\/1+,[{B*}*]{X\_@\%0={Yc\Y):Y'{i={97:Y;}&}{X\}?}fX;`
New: `97:Y;riri:Bri\/),[{B*}*]{X\_@\%0={Yc\Y):Y'{i={97:Y;}&}{X\}?}fX;`

By changing `1+` to `)` we can cut off a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>71</s> 69 bytes

```hs
(a#b)c=do n<-[0,b..c];[show n,[['a'..]!!mod(div n a)26]]!!(0^mod n a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZHJahtREEX3/oo2ClgCW7yaq0j8B9llKRxQT@rW0K1Ztn9eaYt4EectL5dzT/Ga@WFVrdfX63g@yifFc9ln3Y@nWXrMp9Pi5fvs0PSXrHuczR7mD9Ppy/39pi/HZXvOumw@QX0ZknH6PYS34LqZt132nJX9XbY9HX8d9z@77Fs25hFOIKW77OlpjrkWkErgCrxGXKA2lFriJfmKcc26kdQJ9@JbxZ3q3tLB@Gh@cjy7XiK9Br@Fv9/9uxEjmoDxbYM0BwQpEJBLSkQVBWPNLrAQ09SoarQm5ktnt1VQ6BoSQpINfDzuABMg9YABhFsgB4YdsIGkPYiCxAFUQP34MfqvCqThXvl7Lqt/yDAoeIGIjIpeEhKTkleMzKzs9RcGyggmKDfGIMKi5gFpcEOggTZMg4FD4KA9YAk5/4LQkU7Yb4S8KKt60bT/NeizQXkUICVChVYTLSgalq99HJw@/xFyKqS0KmqABVAD0oItIVYIa6QNSofWY2wJdkR7kgPZkeLEcGa6sLyyvXG8C8yFcpFCrJSoFGqlhUqj1mosDVZGa5ONWWfRO2yddi57t4PHMeAUdA65hL1GvF3/AA)

---

**Previous 71 bytes:**

```hs
(a#b)c=do n<-[0,b..c];last$show n:[[['a'..]!!mod(div n a)26]|mod n a<1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZHLTuNAEEX3fIVRkCDSEHW9u2bgD2Y3yygLP2Mnjp3EeQCaf884aFgAteqSrs49pa7TYV227eXykE6yaf5c9En39DgPP7LZLF/8atPhcDfU/Tnpfs7n8/v0fjZb3N5u@uKhaE5Jl6RT1MXfcb@@n2Bx2aRNlzwnRX@TbI@HP4f97y65Sx54glMI4SZ5fEwx0xxCAVxCrBCXqDWFhnhFcc3Ysm4kdMK9xK3iTnVvYTA@WDxGPEU9e3hxfvX4dvO5wyc0BeP3DtIMECRHQC4oEJXkjBVHgaWYhlpVvTGxuIocbe3k2kJACLKB63AHGACpB3Qg3AJFYNgBG0jYgyiID6ACGg/X0s8qEMZ75f@5rPEqw6AQc0RkVIwFITEpxZKRmZVj9YWBMoEpyjtjFGFRiw5hdEOgkTZWg0EEx1F7xBJy9gWhE51yfCdkeVFWy7r5lqCPBGWegxQIJVpFtCSvWb7mcXT6@EfIKJfCSq8AlkA1SAO2Al8jtEgblA6tR98S7Ij2JAPZgfzIcGI6s7ywvbK/CaRCmUguVoiXCpXSUqVWa9RXBmuj1mRj1pn3EbaRdlH20YboB4ej08nl7Pbi/nr5Bw)

**Explanation:**

```hs
(a#b)c=                         -- given the inputs a, b and c
  do n<-[0,b..c];               -- take n from the range from 0 to c with increments of b
  last$   :[   |mod n a<1]      -- if n is not divisible by a
       show n                   -- then use n converted to a string
            [   mod(div n a)26] -- otherwise divide n by a 
             ['a'..]!!          -- and use the character at this position in the alphabet
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 22 bytes

```
ＮθＮη⭆Φ⊕Ｎ¬﹪ιη⎇﹪ιθι§β÷ιθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYvBCoMwEETv@QqPG0hBS2@eCqWQg1JofyCapQbiRsNG2q9PI704l8e8YcbJxDEYn7OmJXGf5gEjrLIVxz6V/oiOGJ5c8O7MAnfnuUyaxogzEqOF40VKVfWBoQs2@QBOVZPc3Qsjmfg9@LXYgitrsviBQVWa@OY2Z/E/72lzvoizaOo6nzb/Aw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ                      Input `a`
  Ｎη                    Input `b`
       Ｎ                Third input (`c`)
      ⊕                 Increment
     Φ                  Filter over implicit range
           η            `b`
          ι             Current value
         ﹪              Modulo
        ¬               Not (i.e. divisible)
    ⭆                   Map over result and join
              ι         Current value
               θ        `a`
             ﹪          Modulo
            ⎇           Ternary
                ι       Current value
                    ι   Current value
                     θ  `a`
                   ÷    Divide
                  β     Predefined lowercase alphabet
                 §      Cyclically index
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Żmọ⁵œpƊżJṖØaṁƲ$F
```

A full program taking arguments `c b a` which prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9qZWxsef//xbtt4buN4oG1xZNwxorFvErhuZbDmGHhuYHGsiRG////MTc0/zP/OQ)**

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc/clang), <s>80</s> 68 bytes

```
f(a,b,c,i){for(i=0;i<=c;i+=b)i%a?printf("%d",i):putchar(i/a%26+97);}
```

Port of my Java [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170224/79343). Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##ZZDNboMwDIDvPIUVCSkRnkooLetStgepegihbD6sVIXtMJRnZyZ0Eu0Sy46cz7/u6d25cWykxQodkhqa9iqpTA3tS2coKStFsX27XOncN1LEtWDo5fLVuw/L4MrG2TbZFcr48bulGvpT10tmwSJMppqNUzBEsDh/CWVcYxAF5SsInOI4xilzh98afPByG50Ugr0@mqp8WjrLZaXQyOEIJQw57lCnmG1wy1d7cwdVM5ThGjPUDKz/IW5GdJqiLnLchFz58yRZsWDDApknplPDZg8d/ZxaHkGtbi/@VwaShB7XEtZnD3TkLQTtWC@m9pEffwE).

Comment: Suggest `printf(L"搥挥"+!(i%a),i%a?i:i/a%26+97)` instead of `i%a?printf("%d",i):putchar(i/a%26+97)`

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 117 bytes

```
#(loop[R""A 0 i 0](if(> i %3)R(let[?(=(mod i %)0)](recur(str R(if ?(char(+(mod A 26)97))i))(if ?(inc A)A)(+ i %2)))))
```

Such imperative. :/

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
Żmµ⁵ḍaÄ$aị¥Øao
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9qZWxsef//xbttwrXigbXhuI1hw4QkYeG7i8Klw5hhb////zEwMP8y/zQ)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2 and 3 - <s>123</s> 128 Bytes

```
d=-1
lambda a,b,c:[s()if i%a<1else i for i in range(0,c+1,b)]
def s():global d;d=(d+1)%26;return'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[d]
```

You'll need to put `f=` in front of the `lambda` and then call it with `f(a,b,c)` but I'm pretty sure that's allowed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>59 58</s> 55 bytes

```ruby
->a,b,c{[w=?a]+b.step(c,b).map{|x|x%a>0?x:w=w.next[0]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ncy7CsMgAEbhvU/RpdDLX1Gj6QVMHkQcNCRbirQpWhKf3ZpCt48znOfbffKg8rmxcOhmHVRrzcmR19T7fQd3IKP18xKXuLMNbeM9qEAefZw0NSllrQU4GKUG@oYK7CKKGC1Rro1LMHBZVKOGuP5QrTD/8cZvB32MJuUv)

Returns a list